# здравствуйте, делаю игру "камень ножницы бумага" на python, в моём коде не накапливается счёт побед, помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import Label

root = Tk()
root.title("камень ножницы бумага")
root.config(background='white')
root.geometry('600x300')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

labelText = Label(root, text='', fg='black', font=('Times New Roman', 20), bg='white')
labelText.place(y=400, x=200)

lbl = Label(root, text='СЧЁТ:', fg='black', font=('Times New Roman', 20), bg='white')
lbl.place(y=180, x=260)

def knb(player_choice):
    ResUser = 0
    ResPc = 0
    computer_choice = random.choice(['камень', 'ножницы', 'бумага'])
    if computer_choice == player_choice:
        labelText.config(text=f'{computer_choice} vs {computer_choice}, ничья')
    elif computer_choice == 'камень' and player_choice == 'бумага':
        labelText.config(text=f'{player_choice} vs {computer_choice}, Вы выиграли!')
        ResUser += 1
    elif computer_choice == 'бумага' and player_choice == 'камень':
        labelText.config(text=f'{player_choice} vs {computer_choice}, Выиграл компьютер:(')
        ResPc += 1
    elif computer_choice == 'камень' and player_choice == 'ножницы':
        labelText.config(text=f'{player_choice} vs {computer_choice}, Выиграл компьютер:(')
        ResPc += 1
    elif computer_choice == 'ножницы' and player_choice == 'камень':
        labelText.config(text=f'{player_choice} vs {computer_choice}, Вы выиграли!')
        ResUser += 1
    elif computer_choice == 'ножницы' and player_choice == 'бумага':
        labelText.config(text=f'{player_choice} vs {computer_choice}, Выиграл компьютер:(')
        ResPc += 1
    elif computer_choice == 'бумага' and player_choice == 'ножницы':
        labelText.config(text=f'{player_choice} vs {computer_choice}, Вы выиграли!')
        ResUser += 1

    lb = Label(root, text=f'Вы:{ResUser}-Компьютер:{ResPc}', fg='black', font=('Times New Roman', 20), bg='white')
    lb.place(y=220, x=185)


labelText.pack()
stone = Button(root,
               text='камень',
               font=('Times New Roman', 15),
               bg='white',
               command=lambda: knb('камень')
               )
stone.place(x=50, y=300)
stone.pack()

scissors = Button(root,
                  text='ножницы',
                  font=('Times New Roman', 15),
                  bg='white',
                  command=lambda: knb('ножницы')
                  )
scissors.pack()

paper = Button(root,
               text='бумага',
               font=('Times New Roman', 15),
               bg='white',
               command=lambda: knb('бумага')
               )
paper.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вынесите определение `ResUser`, `ResPc` перед функцией `knb()`, а в начале функции добавьте строку `global ResUser, ResPc`

Comment: S.Nick спасибо!